# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list and other Codewars help needed

Tags: python

I am currently trying to solve a problem in Codewars.
The problem is:

Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.

It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b keeping their order.

array_diff([1,2],[1]) == [2]
If a value is present in b, all of its occurrences must be removed from the other:

array_diff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]

The code I have tried is:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
result = a
for i in a:
    while i in b:
        result.remove(i)
        
    
return result
```

I am getting this error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

I also tried to replace while with if, but then some of the tests I pass, but some I fail.
For example the code with if instead of while fails this:

a was [1,2,2], b was [2], expected [1]: [1, 2] should equal [1]

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify a list while iterating over it.

Instead, create a new list and have it replace the contents of `a`:

```py
def array_diff(a, b):
    a[:] = [item for item in a if item not in b]
```

You can also make this faster by creating a set first:

```py
def array_diff_2(a, b):
    b_set = set(b)
    a[:] = [item for item in a if item not in b_set]
```

Comment: The way I read it, the task doesn't even say to modify the original list, so `return [i for i in a if i not in b]` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

try this for remove 'a' items present in 'b'

```
def array_diff(a, b):
   for i in a :
       if i in b :
           del b[b.index(i)]
```

or this for remove 'results' items if is in 'a' and in 'b'

```
def array_diff(a, b, results):
   for i in a :
       if i in b :
           del results[results.index(i)]
   return results
```

sorry for my English :)